# Why am I missing a picture while using OpenCV Stitching?

Tags: opencv, opencv-stitching

I am stitching together four pictures. Here is my code:

```
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create()

img1 = cv2.imread("Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper2.jpg")
img3 = cv2.imread("Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper3.jpg")
img4 = cv2.imread("Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper4.jpg")

result = stitcher.stitch((img1,img2,img3,img4))



cv2.imshow("camera",result[1])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

--- My very first picture is not showing up. What would cause all three of my other pictures to stitch but not one of them? I am using Python and OpenCV Stitcher. Help!

This is the newspaper with the top cut off. It is blurry since I had to resize to fit on here.

[image]

Comment: I never used the highlvl stitcher, but did you try to feed the first image twice?

Comment: @Micka I just tried it and nothing happened. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: It certainly would be helpful if you share your sample images, then others can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Markus I have added a link to a picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I can reproduce this issue with the newspaper sample images from the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html). Even with `cv2.Stitcher.create(mode=cv2.STITCHER_SCANS)` as suggested in the tutorial the first image is omitted. My current `opencv` version is opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.64.

It seems someone else has already reported this as a bug: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21010.

---

If I take four photos of a normal landscape the `stitcher` does a good job. I also tried it with a photo of a newspaper and cut it into four overlapping images (upper left, upper right, lower left, lower right, approx. 1700 x 2400 px each) and everything was stitched together.

My code (which is essentially identical to yours):

```
import cv2


img1 = cv2.imread("newspaper1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("newspaper2.jpg")
img3 = cv2.imread("newspaper3.jpg")
img4 = cv2.imread("newspaper4.jpg")

stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(mode=cv2.Stitcher_SCANS)
status, result = stitcher.stitch([img1, img2, img3, img4])

if status == cv2.Stitcher_OK:
    cv2.imshow("stitch", result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", result)
else:
    print(f"Error code {status}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am just using the sample pictures given on OpenCV to get the hang of doing it. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html <--- There is the link the where I got the example. I would think OpenCV would have images that are acceptable in the program so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: @villasenorbritt Thank you for the explanation! I can reproduce this issue with the newspaper sample images from the tutorial. Even with `cv2.Stitcher.create(mode=cv2.STITCHER_SCANS)` as suggested in the tutorial the first image is omitted.

Comment: Well that makes me feel a lot better! I have been trying to figure out the issue for about two days now. I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem could be an inappropriate high confidence theshold within opencvs default stitcher.

You could try the [stitching package](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) (which uses the opencv stitching module) and set the confidence threshold to 0 (since you know that all images are part of the panorama)

so do `pip install stitching` and

```
from stitching import Stitcher

imgs = ["Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper1.jpg",
        "Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper2.jpg",
        "Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper3.jpg",
        "Stitching/Images/Newspapers/Newspaper4.jpg"]

stitcher = Stitcher(matcher_type="affine",   
                    estimator="affine", 
                    adjuster="affine",        
                    wave_correct_kind="no",  
                    warper_type="affine",
                    compensator="no"
                    # these are the values for cv2.STITCHER_SCANS +
                    confidence_threshold=0)
panorama = stitcher.stitch(imgs)
```

Comment: This code threw a couple of errors. But nonetheless, I get your point about the threshold and appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got my last shot. Apparently the Feature Detector used for the newspaper example was `–features surf`. If [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) is not available (which it isn't for opencv-python), surf is not available, and ORB is used by default. Somehow ORB does not work well with the newspaper example. Changing to SIFT solves this issue and lead to the following matches graph

[image]

I used the [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) package with `pip install stitching`

and then

```
stitch newspaper* --affine --detector sift --matches_graph_dot_file matches.txt
```

Comment: Where in the code do you input the "stitch newspaper* --affine --detector sift --matches_graph_dot_file matches.txt " part?

Comment: Its a command line tool. OpenCV Stitcher class does not support changing the feature detector I guess